# py2neo.database.status.CypherSyntaxError: Variable not defined

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to export data from python to neo4j db using py2neo package.
I've a dataframe'ranked_conts' containing a number content is which are string and their corresponding ranks which are in float.
my code is

```
findnode = list(graph.find('rank',property_key='type',property_value='TrendingRank'))

if len(findnode) > 0:
    print("already exist")
else:
    for i in range(len(ranked_conts)):
        conts = ranked_conts.iloc[i]['content_id']
        rank = ranked_conts.iloc[i]['rank']
        graph.run("MERGE(c:Content{contentId:"+str(conts)+"})-[hr: HAS_RANK{r:"+str(rank)+"}]->(rank:Rank {type: 'TrendingRank'})")
```

but when I execute it I'm getting an error message as py2neo.database.status.CypherSyntaxError: Variable `EROS_6272897` not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use parameters instead of creating a new query for every `i in range`. Something like:

```
findnode =list(graph.find('rank',property_key='type',property_value='TrendingRank'))

if len(findnode) > 0:
    print("already exist")
else:
    for i in range(len(ranked_conts)):
        conts = ranked_conts.iloc[i]['content_id']
        rank = ranked_conts.iloc[i]['rank']
    graph.run("MERGE (c:Content{contentId:{cId}})-[hr: HAS_RANK{r:{rankValue}}]->(rank:Rank {type: 'TrendingRank'})",cId = str(conts),rankValue = str(rank))
```

This should speed up your query and make it easier to check for syntax error. One note is also you probably want to merge `:Content` and `:Rank` separately and then `MERGE` the relationship on to it. Like this.

```
MERGE (c:Content{contentId:{cId}})
MERGE (rank:Rank {type: 'TrendingRank'})
MERGE (c)-[hr: HAS_RANK{r:{rank}}]->(rank)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! It worked.. But every time when I run it, a new node is created but Content node is already present.

Comment: see the second part where i told you to merge every node separately and then merge relationship on to it